# ReactJS: How to add an unsupported React component (JSX tag)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are few tags which are not yet defined in ReactJS, like `<animate>` within SVG namespace.

How are basic nodes like `React.DOM.div` and `React.DOM.span` defined in React? Or How are basic tags like `<div>` and `<span>` defined in JSX?

Can I use the same method for extending React to define the standard `<animate>` tag? I don't want to fork and extend the React Github project.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest (and ugliest) way to do this, is to render using dangerouslySetInnerHTML: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html You'd simply generate the `<animate>` tag as string as pass it to a wrapping div as innerHTML.

Otherwise you'll need to dig into the React internals and namely the `createDOMComponentClass` function in `ReactDOM.js`. If you do go that far, I bet you can request a pull request to get the tag merged.

Comment: I can't wrap <animate> tag with any other tag, because SVG animate always relates to its parent element.

Comment: To make this slightly less horrible you can also make a react component called 'animate' yourself which essentially does the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` wrapping with logic to produce the correct string from sent props.  This allows you to then use <animate> 'as normal' in other components, and have a central area to debug it if needed.  When I did this I also put a little check just before the React.createClass() call to check see if React.DOM.animate exists, if it does then in developer mode it gives me an error so if I update to a version which includes it, it'll tell me :)

Comment: I find it funny that such a simple thing is so hard to implement in React.

Comment: This is an unfortunate side effect of SVG being such a huge and strange beast. We added a lot of tags as people needed them but to fully support is actually pretty annoying. We hope to move towards a better model in the future - we know SVG is definitely important moving forward!